# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory'

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, asp.net-identity

Following is the exact exception I am getting while running my .NET application.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in Generic.Helpers.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, Version=2.28.1.741,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have a console application which references a private assembly (.dll). The assembly is referencing to Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory, and I have also added a NuGet package for this in the project

```
<package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.1" targetFramework="net46" />
```

I can see the DLLs are being referenced correctly in the project. However, while running the application, I am getting an error as mentioned above.

Just to give you a brief overview of the class library project - this DLL has methods to connect to CRM web api. This was working fine until last few days, and suddenly stopped working and throwing the error.

I am also consuming the same DLL in Azure function which is where it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: May be you don't have that specific version? have you tried setting specific version to false in properties?

Comment: Check the DLL file architecture, **x86** or **x64**. Perhaps your app needs specific architecture of the file.

Comment: @Ali - the DLL architecture looks OK, it is x64, and this particular Nuget package doesn't have specific assemblies for 32 and 64 bit versions

Comment: @Prajwal - yes, there is a difference in revision numbers of the DLLs, and the specific version is set to True in this case. But I guess this should be OK considering the package has been installed using NuGet package manager.

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed the nuget package without doing any changes, and it started working again. Though its working now, I am not convinced with the solution :(

Comment: When you check the reference properties, is "copy local" set to true?

Comment: @Nirman I think that's the issue. NuGet gives a lot of headache when working with different versions. Just check that property once to false. That did help me in one situation.

Comment: @Prajwal - thanks, but just wondering is it not Nuget's job to handle the correct references? I mean, why should we turn on specific version? will it not create any problem if we install upgraded version later on?

Comment: @Nirman NuGet won't handle the references in the program. It just manages packages. This issue is with visual studio. If Nuget updates some packages and your program asks for specific version, you will definitely get problems.

Comment: @Nirman By the way, issue resolved?

Comment: @Prajwal - yes, the issue got resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling of Nuget package. I didnt change the specific version property to False, but I will do it so that I dont face this issue in future. However, I still believe this should be managed automatically by Nuget. Please put your comments in the answer, and I will mark it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you don't have that specific version? have you tried setting specific version to false in properties?

NuGet won't handle the references in the program. It just manages packages. This issue is with visual studio. If NuGet updates some packages and your program asks for specific version, you will definitely get problems.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when nuget package versions are not same across all projects in the solution. 
Solution->Nuget Package manager-> browse for package

If there are different versions, make them uniform across projects. Issue should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

This was my situation and what worked for me:

I was using the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` version 3.19 in a class library project but only had version 2.22 installed in the actual ASP.NET Web Application project. Upgrading to 3.19 in the web app project got me past the error.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me when I downgraded my dll to  version 2.28.3 from 3.19 to support "AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode" functionality.  After reinstallation it was still redirecting to  version 3.19  because it was still binded to version 3.19 in web.config file. I did  find all search for 3.19 with *.* file type  and commented the setting which was referring 3.19.   like one in web.config below

```
<!--<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.19.8.16603" newVersion="3.19.8.16603" />
      </dependentAssembly>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by switching to PowerShell 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the \bin and \obj folders in my project fixed this for me.

(Other solutions did not - the actual versions where already correct and matching).