# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel,' ver 8

Tags: c#, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting

I have Install 'Microsoft.Reportviewer' in Config file. as

```
<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"  
type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, 
Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />`
```

but facing error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

is there any way to solve this

Comment: add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"   ----- Added this in web.config under httphandeller

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of the file. Set the property **specific version** to `false` in visual studio. That should work.

For more reference check this post.

[Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799580/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identitymodel-clients-activedirectory/40801122#40801122)

Comment: I am running this on IIS

Comment: In visual studio, select the solution, in properties window, change the specific version property to false.